# Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, exception

I would like to catch an unhandled exception that causes my application to silently close.

I have read that there is

```
Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException
```

My application however uses a form to run and the application framework, not a sub main.

The example on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx) seems to rely on a sub main, as it seems to me.

Could somebody tell me how to install the exception handler for a project that uses the application framework?

I have tried the following:

I have changed my application to use a Sub Main instead and used the following code:

```
Public Sub Main()

    ' Set the unhandled exception mode to force all Windows Forms errors to go through'
    ' our handler. '
    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException)

    ' Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions to the event. '
    AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf frmMain.UIThreadException


    ' Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions to the event. '
    AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf frmMain.CurrentDomain_UnhandledException

    ' Runs the application. '
    Application.Run(New frmMain())
End Sub
```

However, the error I am getting is:

```
"The thread exception mode can no longer be changed as soon as controls were created in this thread".
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_. And where do you see _anything_ about `Sub Main`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: We must be looking at different examples. The [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) I'm looking at does not use `Sub Main`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Try Catch to avoid an application from closing by exception. You could try something like

```
    Try
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!")
        Dim A As Integer = 0
        Dim I As Integer
        For I = 1 to 500000000000
            A*=I
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Error occurred")
    End Try
```

This is a little example in a Console Application program, but you will be able to use something like in your project. 
The generic Exception catches every kind of exception you could have, so also Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException. 
Your program shouldn't crash anymore with a try statement.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Try / Catch does not work with my kind of error. I do know where the crash occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to also register an event handler for the case that some exception does not get caught at runtime.

It allows you to log the exception cause and to exit application in a controlled manner.

But as already said, you should primarily use Try Catch statements to catch exceptions in first instance.

Comment: Please provide us the complete source code or at least explain what you are doing.